# Embedding HTML code in Power Automate table

Tags: html, power-automate

I have a Power Automate flow that uses the "Create HTML Table" function as one of its steps. One of the fields in the table is a URL address. The latter can be quite long and makes the display of the table in the email to which it is sent quite crowded. The link appears as the full address. I would prefer to have a label displayed so that when it's clicked the reader gets sent to the underlying link. I know how to create a labeled link in a regular HTML page. However, I'm trying various ways to embed the labeled URL into the table created by Create HTML Table. For example, I've something like this: [Click for Google](https://google.com). The table that is generated shows the link but ignores the label section.

Any advice?

Comment: Can you add 'the various ways' you tried [to your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/70450607/edit)?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to use the table in the email, it should be all done with HTML tags.

1. You need to built that HTML code for link, expression inside "Create HTML table" might look like this:

```
concat('<a href="', body()?['{Link}'], '">Short Name for link</a>')
```

> Concat function connect multiple strings together. In the example it
> connects first part of HTML tag, inserting dynamic content `body()?['{Link}']`, and rest of the HTML tag.

HTML table will not allow you to add another HTML tags as it could break the table. It will end up as a plain text in the email body + It will replace `<` with `&lt;`  ||  `>` with `&gt;`  ||  `“` with `&quot;`

2. You must replace those characters back. - In Email body insert this Expression:

```
replace(replace(replace(body('Create_HTML_table'),'&lt;','<'),'&gt;','>'),'&quot;','"')
```

now the table will display correct short URL links in the email as desired.